# How to store json file content(Secret Key) on Azure key-vault secrets, using powerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

The json file may have one or more blocks of data as shown below.

```
[
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "123456.Abcv.WFcvsdfa",
        "SecretKey":  "NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy"
    }
]
```

OR

```
[
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "753456.Abcv.WFcvsdfa",
        "SecretKey":  "NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy"
    },
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "9045647.GQERDF.GDEAGJWSasdf",
        "SecretKey":  "OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MT"
    }
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "1523456.Abcv.WFcvsdfa",
        "SecretKey":  "NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy"
    },
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "3645647.GQERDF.GDEAGJWSasdf",
        "SecretKey":  "OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MT"
    }
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "5423456.Abcv.WFcvsdfa",
        "SecretKey":  "NDRkNDJjOTAtZjBhYi00NctYjkwYTNlMjNmZTQy"
    },
    {
        "ApplicationName":  "6445647.GQERDF.GDEAGJWSasdf",
        "SecretKey":  "OTlmMmMxYjgtZjEzMS00MTkwLWI1NDQtYjI2MT"
    }
]
```

**The secrets name should be ApplicationName. Dots must be removed from the application name.**

Thanks, appreciate a lots your help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got the solution for this post, may it will be helpful for others in future.

```
$VaultName = "test900066"
$hashtable = Get-Content 'out.json' | ConvertFrom-Json 

foreach ($h in $hashtable.GetEnumerator()) {
    
    $SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $h.SecretKey -AsPlainText -Force
    $ApplicationName = $h.ApplicationName -Replace '\.',''
    # Write-Host "$($ApplicationName) : $SecureString"
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $ApplicationName -SecretValue $SecureString
}
```